# Best practices to Prepare shared Ubuntu AMI with boto3

Tags: python, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-ami

I am creating some share AMI base on Ubuntu in steps:

1. create instance
2. Run some Ansible deployment
3. create image from the instance
4. Terminate instance

After that i created instance from AMI and recognize that authorized_keys contains key of instance from which this AMI was created.

Can you share some code ideas of cleaning the instance before creating AMI or if it is possible to clean AMI once it is created.

Can it be done with boto3 requests only? Or i should run some commands on the instance (with SSM or paramiko).

Will appreciate for the python code examples.

Comment: I would suggest creating the AMI using AWS Image Builder instead.
Image Builder allows you to prepare images like a CI/CD script or Docker image. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/imagebuilder/latest/userguide/what-is-image-builder.html

Comment: @michail_w that is good suggestion, but on current task i think i can do it only with ec2 :(.